# hector_slam and hokuyo_node

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, hokuyo-node, hector-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is the Hokuyo_node included somewhere in the Hector_slam files or does it need to be added separately?

Does it go in the same workspace with Hector_Slam or other (please specify)?

If added separately, does it need to be linked to Hector_slam in any specific way?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40345/hector_slam-and-hokuyo_node/) by [TJump](https://answers.ros.org/users/2785/tjump/) on ROS Answers with karma: 160 on 2012-08-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The hokuyo_node is not started in the launch files, as the LIDAR configuration is highly dependent on the specific setup (which LIDAR, which serial port etc.). By default, most examples use the "/scan" topic for the LIDAR, which also happens to be the default setting for hokuyo_node, so no special treatment is required. Note that you'll have to supply the necessary tf transforms as described [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_slam/Tutorials/SettingUpForYourRobot).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TJump](https://answers.ros.org/users/2785/tjump/) on 2012-08-01**:
Makes perfect sense... make hector_slam multi-LIDAR capable. We have Hokuyo scanners to start with so I will get the hokuyo_node. Thanks for the help.